# Do I need to Dispose XmlReader if I Dispose its underlying Stream?

Tags: c#, dispose, xmlreader, streamreader

I have the following method `GetData` that creates a `StreamReader` from a file.

```
private void GetData(string file)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        Stream bs = sr.BaseStream;
        Stream cl = mainParser.CleanMarkup(bs);
        try
        {
            xmldoc = mainParser.LoadDocument(bs);
        }
        catch (XmlException ex)
        {
            // Exceptions are usually caused by non-compliant documents.
            // These errors are not critical to the operation of this program.
            Console.WriteLine(filename + " " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    Msdn msdnParser = new Msdn(xmldoc);

    ListViewItem lvitem = new ListViewItem(filename);
    lvitem.SubItems.Add(filename);
    foreach (string item in msdnParser.Subitems)
    {
        lvitem.SubItems.Add(item);
    }
    listView.Items.Add(lvitem);
}
```

`mainParser.LoadDocument(bs)` calls the following:

```
public XmlDocument LoadDocument(Stream file)
{
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlReader xmlread = XmlReader.Create(file);
    xmldoc.Load(xmlread);

    return xmldoc;
}
```

`StreamReader` is disposed by `GetData`. Does this mean that I don't have to dispose of `XmlReader` since (I believe) this would dispose of its only unmanaged resource?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best "rule of thumb" to work by is:

*If something implements `IDisposable`, always wrap it in a `using()` block to ensure that any unmanaged resources it owns are disposed of correctly.*

Relying on the fact that the *current* implementation of "something" disposes of an underlying resource is dangerous and it won't hurt to wrap everything in a `using`, just to *be on the safe side* =)

Comment: Ahh, this is a good point. This is probably a concept that I need to keep aware of. Always nice when an example shows up in my face.

Comment: Ah the answer is good for C# only. It would be nice if the answer can be applied to even C++/CLI.

Answer (score 6):

You're right, you don't *have to* dispose the reader. But in the code given, it wouldn't hurt either.

I would not put a using block inside `LoadDocument()` because it is designed so that it 'borrows' it's stream (it does not create it).

But there are arguments to Dispose the XmlReader anyway, just because it's IDisposable.  I don't think there is a clear winner here because of the disputable design of the Reader (and Writer) family: They Dispose their baseStreams without clearly being the owner of those streams.

Comment: Based off of what I read, `XmlReaderSettings` has a property `CloseInput` that defaults to `true`. Should I consider disabling this default behavior so I can dispose of `XmlReader` without disposing the underlying `Stream`?

Comment: My book lied to me. The default value for `CloseInput` is `false`.